# Adding website logo to homescreen from website

Tags: favicon

I have already written a code to add my website logo to my desktop using  and it is working fine. I have also added additional code to have the same thing work for mobile home screen. But, I am having to use the function provided in the browser menu to add the logo to my desktop/homescreen. Is there a way to do it by clicking a link on the webpage itself? (like a link on webpage to bookmark the page)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature.

As a workaround, you can use [AddToHomescreen](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen), a JavaScript widget that asks your visitor to, well, add your website to his home screen.